# How can I retrieve the default value for my jsp dropdown item list?

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu, default-value, items

In my JSP page, I'm utilising a Dropdownlist.
Table provides the values.

My issue is that the first option in the list is displayed as the dropdown list's default value.

When the page loads, I want (—None—) to be the default setting.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Here's where I put my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <form:label path="Id">Forms:</form:label>
            <form:select path="Id" class="form-control"  items="${forms}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked

```
       <form:select path="templateId" class="form-control">
           <form:option value="-1" label="None"/>
           <form:options items="${temps}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
         </form:select>
```